# How to load two sets of 4 shorts into an XMM register?

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, intrinsics

I'm just getting started with SSE intrinsics using Visual C++ 2012 and I need some pointers (no pun intended).

I have two arrays containing 4 `signed short`s each (each array is thus 64-bit, totalling 128). I want to load one into the upper bits of an XMM register, and the other in the lower bits. Can I accomplish this efficiently using SSE intrinsics? If so, how?

Comment: I guess so, but I'd rather use the available intrinsics rather than write the instructions directly, if possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**SSE2:**

```
short A[] = {0,1,2,3};
short B[] = {4,5,6,7};

__m128i a,b,v;
a = _mm_loadl_epi64((const __m128i*)A);
b = _mm_loadl_epi64((const __m128i*)B);
v = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(a,b);

// v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

**SSE4.1 + x64:**

```
short A[] = {0,1,2,3};
short B[] = {4,5,6,7};

__m128i v;
v = _mm_loadl_epi64((const __m128i*)A);
v = _mm_insert_epi64(v,*(const long long*)B,1);

// v = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

---

Note that there are no alignment requirements for `A` or `B`. But I'd recommend that they both be aligned to 8 bytes anyway.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think of doing two loadl_epi64 as in your first example, but then expand that using _mm_unpacklo_epi64 ? Would that work also?

Comment: Yeah, that's actually better. I'll update. Didn't even cross my mind. :)

Comment: Weee I taught the master something (just kidding). Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's what happens when I get spoiled by all the new stuff. I lose my touch with the old things. :)

Comment: I know this is unrelated but what exactly is a "word" and how can I know the word size on my system? I ask this because on an x86 assembly tutorial the tutor said that a word was 16 bits or 2 bytes. But then elsewhere I read that a word was the same size as an int which is 4 bytes.

Comment: @0x499602D2 There's a lot of different definitions of "word". In x86 assembly, a word is 16 bits. In computer architecture, a "word" is usually the "natural working size" of the hardware. So 32-bit hardware would have a 32-bit word. 64-bit hardware would have a 64-bit word.

Comment: In `gcc` at least, the compiler handles `__m128i v = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(*(__m128i*)A, *(__m128i*)B);` and will translate that to a two-instruction sequence `movdqu ...,%xmm0; punpcklqdq ...,%xmm0` with `...` a memory operand, i.e. pretty much the same as SSE4.1; The SSE2 isn't strictly correct because it overruns the inputs on load (and may segfault if either of the two arrays end at a page boundary), but it's less instructions than two `movq` plus the `punpcklqdq`. If your `short` arrays are sufficiently aligned and known not to straddle page boundaries, it'll work.

Comment: Why does the second approach need x64?

Comment: @plasmacel The `_mm_insert_epi64()` intrinsic/instruction doesn't exist in x86.

Comment: @Mysticial Good to know. This information is missing from Intel Instrinsics Guide. It just lists `_mm_insert_epi64` as a casual SSE4.1 intrinsic.

Comment: @plasmacel Yeah. Fundamentally, that instruction (and a few others) take a 64-bit GPR as an operand. And those don't exist on x86. They can also take an 8-byte memory location, but that's just part of the normal encoding scheme that's allowed for GPRs.

Comment: @Mysticial I'm confused now: does it work then on x86 too? Btw is there any source on the web about those few SSE instructions which work only on x64?

Comment: @plasmacel No it does not. I think it's using the same x64 encoding for GPR instructions that can be either a register or a memory operand. But it's still x64-only in both cases. I'm aware of 4 instructions like this, `_mm_insert_epi64()`, `_mm_extract_epi64()`, `_mm_cvtsi64_si128()`, and `_mm_cvtsi128_si64()`.

Comment: Actually, there are more. All the conversion and set instructions/intrinsics which either input or output a scalar 64-bit integer are like this.

Comment: @plasmacel: Intel's insn set reference shows which forms of every instruction is encodable or not in protected/compat (32-bit mode) vs. long mode (64-bit).  e.g. [PINSRQ xmm, r/m64, imm8](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PINSRB:PINSRD:PINSRQ.html) is Valid in 64-bit mode / Not Encodeable in 32-bit mode.  Since there's no alternate form that has an `xmm/m64` source, it's only available in 64-bit mode.  Compare MOVQ: http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVD:MOVQ.html vs. http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVQ.html where there is an alternate form due to the MMX ancestry, but intrinsics can be weird.

Comment: If your source operand is 16B-aligned, the compiler may be able to PUNPCKLQDQ with a memory source operand (especially if you use `_mm_load_si128()` to hint it that that's ok).  With AVX, there's no alignment requirement, but then you'd have to worry about reading off the end of a page into a potentially-unmapped page.  Or if shuffle-port throughput is a bottleneck, you could use a `vpblendd` or `pblendw` with a memory operand that starts 8 bytes before the second array.  So the load address takes care of getting the data lined up with the upper half, instead of needing an ALU shuffle.